# Error:Printer halted. kill() called!

Tags: marlin, troubleshooting, pronterface

When printing cube.gcode using Pronterface I get:

```
Print started at: 23:07:31
```

After 8 seconds I get:

```
Error:Printer halted. kill() called!
Error:Printer halted. kill() called!
```

What is the reason?
How can I see logs?

Additional information:

I connected only three motors, and set the following in Configuration.h of Marlin Firmware:

```
#define TEMP_SENSOR_0 999
...
#define TEMP_SENSOR_BED 999
...
#define X_MIN_ENDSTOP_INVERTING true // set to true to invert the logic of the endstop.
...
```

(Also for min max for XYZ)

In 8 second X motor and Z motor were running.

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ePtdnp2bPZXrOXZcE9inYSxHUbInyVnb) is the link to G-Code print file (cube.gcode).

I'm using Marlin 1.1.x on a Arduino Mega 2560 + RAMPS 1.4 without endstops.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3D Printing.SE! The question is a little terse to answer, please add what exactly happens in the 8 seconds? Does the printhead home to the limit switches? Does it try to heat up the nozzle?

Comment: To find the reason, we need more info. E.g. o you have end stops? And do you home the axes in the G-code. Adding a link to the G-code file could be helpful!

Comment: Could you please help me understand "I connected only three motors."  An FDM 3D printer usually has at least 4 motors, three to cover the 3 x-y-z degrees of freedom, and the extruder.

Comment: I did it only for test purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your G-code file contains the `G28` command to home the printer, as you do not have endstops, execution of this command fails. If you do not use endstops, you should never home the printer, instead you must position the print head at the origin yourself (generally this would be at coordinate [x=0, y=0, z="paper thickness"]) and remove homing commands from your G-code file.

Comment: It helped. But I detect new problem. https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8482/after-some-time-stepper-motor-is-hot